# Subsets of a group as an algebraic structure

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $F$ be a set and $.$ be a binary operation on $F$ and $.^{-1}:F\to F$ be a so-called inverse operation on $F$ such that $(F,.)$ is semigroup and for each $x,y\in F$,

$$(x^{-1})^{-1}=x,~~~~~ (xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}$$

Then $(F,.,^{-1})$ is called an **Ef Stucture**.

An ef structure is called **derived** if it is isomorphic to some $(\mathcal F,.,^{-1})$ where $\mathcal F\subseteq \mathcal P(G)$ for a group $G$.

Which ef structures are derived? Is there an algebraic (structural) characterization?

Comment: Do you also require $(x.y)^{-1}=(y^{-1}).(x^{-1})$?

Comment: @UwF: Clearly it is a requirement to be derived. Yes It can be added to the definition of ef structure.

Comment: I *think* you are suggesting that $P(G)$ carries such a structure. Are you really asking which Ef structures occur as *substructures* of such $P(G)$? or just asking for abstract characterizations of $P(G)$ (which is what the title suggests)?

Comment: As substructure.  $\mathcal F\subseteq \mathcal P(G)$ is a (derived) ef structure iff it is closed under multiplication and inverse.

Comment: If you have for all $x, y$ that $x . x^{-1} = y . y^{-1}$, then you have an associative binary operation with identity and right inverses (by the group definition), which is enough to give you the group structure. So I think that that's necessary and sufficient.

Comment: Hrm. Actually, that isn't enough; it doesn't give you full identity.

Comment: Probably it becomes simpler if one assumes $F$ is a poset with normal properties derived from subgroups of a group.